# How do I prevent users from changing form values or removing input fields elements using inspector tool?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I have a form that has a few radio buttons, required fields and tick boxes that need to be completed before submitting. I have been testing the form a little bit and using the inspector tool I was able to change the values of the radio buttons, remove the required fields elements and remove the tick buttons elements and it submitted to my database without any problems.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Example of my form fields:

```
<input type="checkbox" required  name="terms">I agree to the <a href="/terms-and-conditions" target="_blank"> Terms and Conditions</a></label>

<input type="radio" name="medicalAilments" value="No">No</label>

<input type="email" id="userEmail" class="form-control" required name="userEmail">
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: **you cannot.** And even if you somehow could disable editing in the web browser, what's keeping your clients from mocking a malformed request using cURL? I'm assuming you are posting this form to a web server, in which case you should do validation on your server and return an error if a required field was not present. A good rule of thumb is to **never trust the client**. It's trivial to modify requests and add / remove / modify values.

Comment: So basically I should be doing additional verification in the backend.

Comment: Yes, you should always verify on the backend. You can do **additional** verification on the client, but this is purely for user experience. A malicious user can easily bypass any client-side protections.